# Regex validation for description box

Tags: jquery, regex

Have a description box in which ajax is used to count number of characters .
Need to validate the description box for input .
The criteria is that it should allow everything - alphabets, spaces, new line characters, special characters etc.
But , the input cant be **only numbers/special characters/spaces alone !**

Have been stuck on this for quite somewhile now , the regex that I have written leads to catastrophic backtracking error.

Please provide a solution for this .

Comment: So you mean there should be at least one occurance of each alphabets, spaces, new line characters, special characters ?

Comment: @A.J the only requirement is that there should be atleast one alphabet in the description box. Rest it can contain any thing else like numbers , whitespaces, special characters etc.

Comment: @Wiktor , Currently Im using this ^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*$

Comment: It is working as expected for all validations but doesnot work when I press enter and type in the new line . Request you to please halp me with multiline regex as well.

Comment: Replace `.` with `[\s\S]`. However, I can't see your code, it may not work for you as is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ^.*[a-zA-Z]+[\\s\\S]  this is the expression Im using, It fails for new line character. After pressing enter , the regex fails.

Comment: There is no point trying to change the regex, your issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Things allowed: alphabets, special characters, spaces, new line and presumably  numbers
- Things not allowed: ONLY special characters, spaces,numbers  and presumably new line
- which leads to at least one alphabet present in the description

So this `^(.|\s)*[a-zA-Z]+(.|\s)*$` should help you

- `(.|\s)*` --> any character including whitespace, if you want atleast one alphabet on first line then replace this with `.*`
- `[a-zA-Z]+` atleast one alphabet
- `(.|\s)*` --> followed by  any character including whitespace characters(like newline)

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot . I tried . It works for everything . except when I press enter , the validation fails . Could you please tell how can I accomodate any number of enters.

Comment: @shubbi edited the answer to include whitespace characters

Comment: @shubbi if it works, mark the answer as correct , so that others will know

Comment: @shubbi https://regex101.com/r/KZUmmJ/1 here you can test that regex.. it worked for me for multiline characters

Comment: it doesn't work , You have mentioned how it will take in white space . But i'm looking for multiline regex which would allow me any number of new line characters as well . So i can type upto 2000 characters by giving spaces , new line(enter ) etc.

Comment: `(.|\s)*` will cause unnecessary backtracking and might cause a slowdown, it is a very bad construct. Use `[\s\S]*` instead.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , I have tried [\s\S] as well. They dont work for new line characters. It allows only spaces . I want the regex to allow for multiple new line characters as well .

Comment: Then your question is off-topic without code. `[\s\S]` matches *any* character.

Comment: thank you  @WiktorStribiżew  for the optimization.. do u have any links for the common optimizations in regex.?

Comment: General idea is to avoid alternation when you do not need it, avoid nested quantifiers inside a pattern if there is one obligatory pattern and others are optional inside (or all are optional or only one is obligatory), avoid `(.|\s)*` / `(.|\n)*?` etc., use unroll the loop principle when dealing with long texts, avoid `.*` / `.*?` when parsing delimited texts... No idea where you can read about it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, from ur comment in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions i find rexegg.com to be a better tutorial.. thank u

Comment: Thanks a lot all :)